# Unix find -exec show "day of week" file modified

Tags: unix, find, tcsh

Using tcsh

I want to be able to find files and delete them if for example they were created on a Friday.

So far I have the following but I get "Illegal variable name.".

```
find previous/*/fmpsw/ -name "Daily_*" -exec date -r $(stat -f %m '{}') +%A \;
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really need a file's mount point (`%m`) when you call `stat`?

Comment: That doesn't give the file's mount point. It gives the files timestamp.

Comment: You should at least use the backtick for command expansion... `$()` is not supported in `tcsh`.

Comment: Of course, the `stat` command is not portable, hence I might very easily have very different options on my system...

Comment: Thanks - How do you mean backtick for command expansion?

Comment: Write ` ``stat -f %m '{}'`` ` instead of `$(stat -f %m '{}')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.  Find the files.**

Here is a possibile solution

```
find previous/*/fmpsw/ -name "Daily_*" -exec tcsh -c 'date -r `stat -f %m {}` +%A' \;
```

The `{}` needs to be substituted by `find` before it is actually passed to the subshell which is spawn by

```
`stat -f %m {}`
```

**2.  Delete the files.**

Now we want to actually delete the files (e.g., those that were created on Friday).  The construction here is rather more involved:

```
find previous/*/fmpsw/ -name "Daily_*" -type f -exec tcsh -c '  \
    date -r `stat -c %n {}` +%A | grep Friday > /dev/null;      \
    test $? -eq 0 && rm -f {}                                   \
' \;
```

Here we use `grep` to filter based on the chosen day-of-week.

Comment: That's great thanks, I just need to add an if statement to it now.

Comment: Which kind of `if`, exactly?

Comment: If it is a Friday, delete the file